Once decohered, is the quantum system always fully transitioned from superposition of states to one definite, 'classical' state?
Upon detection by an observer or measurement device, an isolated system changes (or collapses) from it's superposition of states to a single state. In decoherence, does an isolated system undergo the same kind of (or dare I say exact?) transition when decohered by it's environment?

Short answer: No. Decoherence describes the interaction between a system and its environment. After this interaction, the system and environment will together be in a superposition of different states. This occurs by default because quantum mechanics is a linear theory. The collapse postulate is an additional rule that justifies why we only see a single outcome in experiments.
Long answer: Zurek has written extensive reviews of decoherence (2001, 2003) which address this question. I've sketched out the general ideas in an example below:
Consider a particle moving through space. The state of this particle may be described as a superposition of different position states. I'll denote two of them using $|x\rangle$ and $|y\rangle$.
Suppose there is a slight interaction between the particle and its immediate surroundings, which I'll call the environment. (This is generally the case$-$quantum systems are trickly to isolate for extended periods of time.) Like the particle, the environment can also be treated quantum-mechanically. I'll call the initial state of the environment $|\varepsilon\rangle$. During the interaction, the state of the environment will change in response to the system. I'll introduce the states $|\varepsilon_x\rangle$ and $|\varepsilon_y\rangle$ to represent the final state of the environment, for a particle sitting in the $|x\rangle$ and $|y\rangle$ states respectively. Then, because quantum mechanics is linear, an arbitrary superposition of these position states evolves to
$$
(a |x\rangle + b |y\rangle) |\varepsilon\rangle \rightarrow a |x\rangle |\varepsilon_x\rangle + b |y\rangle |\varepsilon_y\rangle
$$
Often, the environment states will be orthogonal to each other, that is $\langle \varepsilon_x | \varepsilon_y\rangle = 0$. This entanglement with orthogonal environment states destroys the interference between the original position states; if you let the particle evolve and measured it later, you would no longer see interference effects.
(Feynman actually exemplifies this in volume III, part 3$-$2 of his lectures; the $x$ and $y$ states represent the particle at the locations of the slits, and the light source is the environment. While he doesn't introduce the term decoherence, I think this works as an example.)
So, decoherence can describe the loss of interference by entanglement with the environment, but it doesn't seem to explain why only one outcome occurs. Rather, this is handled by the collapse postulate. In our example, suppose we perform a measurement right after the decoherence has occurred. The collapse postulate then says that the state changes to
$$
a |x\rangle |\varepsilon_x\rangle + b |y\rangle |\varepsilon_y\rangle \rightarrow \begin{cases}
|x\rangle|\varepsilon_x\rangle & \text{w.p.}\,\,\,|a|^2 \\
|y\rangle|\varepsilon_y\rangle & \text{w.p.}\,\,\,|b|^2 \\
\end{cases}
$$
which is what we observe experimentally. In particular, you could think of the measurement apparatus like the environment this way, since it's just another system that is sensitive to the quantum state.
That said, the question of if, when and how the collapse occurs constitutes the measurement problem, and is currently unsolved. (Or at least, there is no consensus on its resolution.) For instance, the Many-Worlds formulation of quantum mechanics argues that the collapse doesn't need to be postulated at all; observers would go into superpositions just like the environment does, and decoherence of the detector/observer explains why they only perceive one outcome.

Thank you for engaging. I just left a comment, but I want to reword it. When the system and environment are together in that superposition of different states once they've interacted with each other, doesn't the part of the environment (we can say particle) that interacted with the initial system still need to be explained? I.e., since everything is a quantum system, doesn't something in the environment's environment enter into a superposition of different states with the environment before the environment interacts with our aforementioned initial system?

Let's denote $|\varepsilon\rangle$ as the "environment", and $|\delta\rangle$ as the "environment's environment". I can certainly see how, before the interaction with the system, the environment's environment may become entangled with the environment, such that the combined state is like $|\varepsilon_1\rangle |\delta_1 \rangle + |\varepsilon_2 \rangle |\delta_2 \rangle$.
If I understand correctly, your question roughly is "how are we justified in invoking the un-entangled environment state $|\varepsilon\rangle$ when the environment is constantly interacting with its surroundings?"

You could invoke a combined state $|\omega\rangle$, which is just whatever state the environment and environment's environment is in, immediately before the experiment. We can still say that $|\omega\rangle$ evolves into a superposition of $|\omega_x\rangle$ and $|\omega_y\rangle$ after interaction with the "initial system", and make the same argument about them being orthogonal, and interference being lost. In this sense, decoherence is quite agnostic to the exact state the environment is in. But I suppose you could then ask, "what about the environment's environment's environment..?"

Yes, precisely! And I'm sorry for the delayed response, but your last question hit what I'm asking. For every denoted initial system, there is a corresponding environment to it. The environment itself always has its own corresponding environment, and so on and so forth. Mustn't there be an initial environment that breaks this chain you and I acknowledge is inherent to this theory? And of course, this is pressing philosophical discourse more than strictly theoretically scientific discourse at this point, but I still think it's worth discussing.

To finish off my response, I'll phrase the question very straightforwardly: Eventually, shouldn't there be an 'environment' that isnt together with anything else in a superposition of different states?

This seems like an instance of a more general question, which is "how can we ever have factorised states, when systems are constantly becoming entangled with their surroundings?" We asked this about the environment $|\varepsilon\rangle$ and its surroundings, but we could also ask this about an isolated particle in a state $|x\rangle$ as well. The combined state there is $|x\rangle|\text{detector, environment, ...}\rangle$, but where did this factorisation originate from? Particles are constantly interacting with their surroundings, so shouldn't this factorisation be lost?

By framing the question this way, we can relate this question to quantum measurement. Consider a particle and detector in initial states $|x\rangle$ and $|D\rangle$, so the combined state is $|x\rangle|D\rangle$. (Hopefully you can take this factorisation for granted, for the moment.) Suppose that the particle then evolves and interacts with the detector. We then have the combined state $c_1 |x_1\rangle |D_1\rangle + c_2 |x_2\rangle |D_2 \rangle$, so that the factorisation is lost. How can we ever get it back again?

Recall that after the process of measurement, the system "collapses" into the state $|x_1\rangle|D_1\rangle$ or $|x_2\rangle|D_2\rangle$, restoring the factorisation. Perhaps then, a similar thing occurs with the environment $|\varepsilon\rangle$ and the environment's environment $|\delta\rangle$. That is, after the entanglement $|\varepsilon_1\rangle|\delta_1\rangle + |\varepsilon_2\rangle|\delta_2\rangle$, some kind of "measurement" occurs, which brings its state back to $|\varepsilon_1\rangle|\delta_1\rangle$ or $|\varepsilon_2\rangle|\delta_2\rangle$.

Of course, it is rather unclear what "measurement" even means in this context, since we can't draw a clean line between system and observer. In particular, it might seem inconsistent to write the environment as a state which enters a quantum superposition, yet also claim that, at some undefined moment, it collapses back into a single state. (This is what formulations of QM such as Many-Worlds aim to clear up.)

But for now, my point is that measurement/collapse is what breaks entanglement, providing the origin of the factorised states. If we can accept that this occurs for a quantum particle and a detector, and if we think of measurement as a generic interaction between systems, then it seems plausible that a similar process occurs within the environment itself. One's attitude towards the measurement problem will specify how this process occurs. In conclusion, there doesn't need to be an "initial" unentangled state, since factorised states are constantly being broken by the process of measurement.

One's attitude toward the measurement problem certainly will shape how this process occurs in their understanding, I agree. The fact that we can only ever arbitrarily separate a part of the universe, denote it as the system under experimental observation, and label the rest of the universe as it's 'environment', is problematic to me. It is just so arbitrary, and it seems to me that it clearly isn't a theory for the fundamental behavior and constituents of all matter.

On what grounds, if any, do you think I may be unjustified for holding my position? You did admit that one's attitude regarding the measurement problem will shape how they view decoherence theory, and the attitude I have about it is, well, kinda contrary to the mainstream, haha. One's approach with the measurement problem is always a subjective thing, but on what grounds am I unjustified to hold these contrarian views? I thank you again for engaging me with all your insight.

I think your viewpoint is quite justifiable, and actually not that contrarian. I agree that it shouldn't matter how you label the system and the environment$-$physics should just do its thing.

That said, it's not obvious to me that this is a problem for the system vs. environment distinction per se. The quantum system and environment both exist, we're just letting $|x\rangle$ and $|\varepsilon\rangle$ denote whatever their states are. I don't see any trouble in distinguishing, say, and electron in a double quantum well, and the particles in the surrounding substrate. (I'm not sure if this is what you were getting at?)

On the other hand, I can see that there's much ambiguity in what counts as the environment. Is the environment just everything within a cubic centimeter of the system? Does it include the measurement apparatus? Does it include observers? I did find this problematic, when first learning about decoherence.

However, a key intuition is that the details of what you call the environment shouldn't really matter. Suppose you postulate "the wavefunction collapses after it gets entangled with $1,\text{cm}^3$ of the surrounding matter". So the environment $|\varepsilon\rangle$ would be this cubic centimeter of matter. Since this contains lots of particles that move in different ways in response to the quantum system, the environment will evolve into a superposition of orthogonal states, and you get the decoherence I originally described.

But suppose you instead postulate that the collapse occurs a little later, so that the particle first gets entangled with $1,\text{m}^3$ of surrounding matter. Would this make an observable difference?

I claim that it would not; the decoherence argument merely relied on the fact that different environment states are orthogonal to each other. This is quite a generic condition, and is well satisfied in both the aforementioned cases. Thus, the interference experiment works out the same way.

In summary, I think your concern about the arbitrariness of labelling states is quite valid, but it's not obvious to me that it is a problem for decoherence. On the other hand it does seem like a pressing issue for the collapse of the wavefunction...

The equations of motion of quantum theory describe the evolution of physical quantities in terms of Hermitian operators called observables whose eigenvalues are the possible results of measuring those observables. In many experiments the result can only be predicted by taking into account what happens to all of the possible values: quantum interference. See Section 2 of this paper for an example:
https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9911150
A measurement is a physical process that produces a record of some property of the measured system that can be copied, e.g. - you can look at the measurement result and then copy into a notebook, or you can copy a file containing a measurement result and send the copy to somebody else and so on. If we describe records that can be copied using quantum theory we find that in general copying suppresses interference: this is called decoherence
https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.06282
You stated that measurement causes collapse: it changes a system so that it only has one value. The decoherence description of measurement doesn't do that. To produce collapse you would have to modify the equations of motion of quantum theory, e.g. - spontaneous collapse theory
https://arxiv.org/abs/2310.14969
It should be noted that such theories can't currently reproduced the predictions of relativistic quantum theories, which comprise the vast bulk of experimentally tested predictions of quantum theory:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.00568
Quantum theory without such modifications describes reality in terms of multiple versions of each system and predicts that in everyday life those versions sort themselves into layers each of which looks approximately like the universe as described by classical physics
https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.2189
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0104033
This is often called the many worlds interpretation and some physicists don't like it and prefer to modify quantum theory with collapse or other modifications such as pilot waves:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2408.05403
which all have the problems pointed out above. Others just refuse to describe the implications of quantum theory and call this an interpretation of quantum theory, e.g. - the Copenhagen and statistical interpretations.
